# Lodash - Map array of entity/key/value to into an Object with properties

Tags: arrays, lodash

I have the following array:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ABC",
    "type": "iPhone",
    "sessions": "3.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "ABC",
    "type": "Android",
    "sessions": "25.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "ABC",
    "type": "Windows",
    "sessions": "3.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "type": "iPhone",
    "sessions": "1.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "type": "Android",
    "sessions": "11.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "type": "Windows",
    "sessions": "15.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "type": "Outlook",
    "sessions": "10.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "DEF",
    "type": "Windows",
    "sessions": "10.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "GHI",
    "type": "iPhone",
    "sessions": "10.0"
  }
]
```

I would like to convert this to an array of objects as follows using lodash:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ABC",
    "iPhone": "3.0",
    "Android": "25.0",
    "Windows": "3.0",
    "Outlook": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "iPhone": "1.0",
    "Android": "11.0",
    "Windows": "15.0",
    "Outlook": "10.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "DEF",
    "iPhone": "",
    "Android": "",
    "Windows": "10.0",
    "Outlook": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "GHI",
    "iPhone": "10.0",
    "Android": "",
    "Windows": "",
    "Outlook": ""
  }
]
```

Basically the "name" property has to be used as a key to consolidate the properties into an object. Any concise way of doing this with lodash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash's `_.transform()`:

```js
var arr = [{"name":"ABC","type":"iPhone","sessions":"3.0"},{"name":"ABC","type":"Android","sessions":"25.0"},{"name":"ABC","type":"Windows","sessions":"3.0"},{"name":"XYZ","type":"iPhone","sessions":"1.0"},{"name":"XYZ","type":"Android","sessions":"11.0"},{"name":"XYZ","type":"Windows","sessions":"15.0"},{"name":"XYZ","type":"Outlook","sessions":"10.0"},{"name":"DEF","type":"Windows","sessions":"10.0"},{"name":"GHI","type":"iPhone","sessions":"10.0"}];

var result = _.transform(arr, function(products, item) {
    var product = products[item.name] = products[item.name] || {
      name: item.name,
      iPhone: "",
      Android: "",
      Windows: "",
      Outlook: ""
    };

    product[item.type] = item.sessions;

    return products;
  }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

```js
var f = [{
  "name": "ABC",
  "type": "iPhone",
  "sessions": "3.0"
}, {
  "name": "ABC",
  "type": "Android",
  "sessions": "25.0"
}, {
  "name": "ABC",
  "type": "Windows",
  "sessions": "3.0"
}, {
  "name": "XYZ",
  "type": "iPhone",
  "sessions": "1.0"
}, {
  "name": "XYZ",
  "type": "Android",
  "sessions": "11.0"
}, {
  "name": "XYZ",
  "type": "Windows",
  "sessions": "15.0"
}, {
  "name": "XYZ",
  "type": "Outlook",
  "sessions": "10.0"
}, {
  "name": "DEF",
  "type": "Windows",
  "sessions": "10.0"
}, {
  "name": "GHI",
  "type": "iPhone",
  "sessions": "10.0"
}];

var def = {
  "name": "",
  "iPhone": "",
  "Android": "",
  "Windows": "",
  "Outlook": ""
};

function updateMemo(memo, obj) {
  memo[obj.name] = memo[obj.name] || _.extend({}, def, {name: obj.name});
  memo[obj.name][obj.type] = obj.sessions;
  return memo;
}

console.log(_.values(_.reduce(f, updateMemo, {})));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

It consists of performing a reduction on the array storing the values in an intermidiate object. The stored values follow the default structure. Once the array is made, only the values are returned in order to get the expected output.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It possible with lodash `mapKeys` method but your value should be object instead of primitive value.

```js
let orig = {" a ":{rate: 1}, " b ":{rate: 2}};

let result = _.mapKeys(orig, (value, key)=> {
  
  value.rate = value.rate + 1
  return key.trim()
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```